# Delete all lines for which the kth field is 'NA'

Tags: bash, awk, lines

Fix k, say k = 2 for illustration.  Suppose we have a text file, `file.txt`, that has at least k columns, and the columns are delimited by the `|` symbol.  How can I clean `file.txt` by deleting every row with the 2nd column equal to 'NA'?  Lets say the output is directed to `outfile.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '$2 != "NA"' FS='|'
```

Input:

```
111|222|333
444|NA|666
777|888|999
```

Output:

```
111|222|333
777|888|999
```

Comment: To pass `k` as a variable: `awk '$k != "NA"' FS='|' k=2 file.txt` or `awk -F'|' -v k=2 '$k != "NA"' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I dont have access to a PC, but something along the lines of:

```
gawk -F '|' '$2 != "NA"{ print}' file.txt  >outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

grep with inverted matching can do it also:

```
grep -v '^\([^|]\+|\)\{1\}NA|' file.txt > outfile.txt
#                      ^  ^
#                      |  +-- search pattern
#                      +----- number of leading columns
```